# Object is possibly 'undefined' - on window local storage get Item method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
 if (window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('accessToken')?.length > 0) {
  this.navigateToApplication();
}
```

getting an error as :

`Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

how to fix this? I am trying to get the value by  optional here.

Answer (score 2):

This could use a better error message. :-) The problem is that since `window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('accessToken')?` evaluates to `undefined` if the item isn't there, your `if` comparison is `undefined | number > number`, which is problematic from a type perspective.

You can just get rid of the `> 0` since both `undefined` and `0` are falsy:

```
if (window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('accessToken')?.length) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−− Removed `> 0`
    this.navigateToApplication();
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYMwBAFA7sB2AmB7KB+AdAZwKYY8RsAygC6IBOAhgOZbo3ECSxWAthAOQUDGXOGAKogDWWWOwCU6ADaiqxABbiwAbwBQYMAuAY0sCgDdgVCs0EBBAA4WpwLifywI4gNyqAvkA)

Alternatively, provide a default value using nullish coalescing (`??`):

```
if (window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('accessToken')?.length ?? 0 > 0) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
    this.navigateToApplication();
}
```

`window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('accessToken')?.length ?? 0` will evaluate to `0` if the item isn't there, which makes for a `number > number` comparison, which TypeScript is happy with.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYMwBAFA7sB2AmB7KB+AdAZwKYY8RsAygC6IBOAhgOZbo3ECSxWAthAOQUDGXOGAKogDWWWOwCU6ADaiqxABZgUKMAAYwAPjXiwAbwBQYMAuAY0sCgDdgVCs0EBBAA5OpwLnfywI4gNz6AXyA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `window.sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")` might be undefined. That's why you need to check beforehand if your item exists.

```
  const accessToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  if (accessToken && accessToken?.length > 0) {
    this.navigateToApplication();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! But code dumps aren't usually *useful* answers. To make the answer useful, say *what* you did, *why*, and *how* it works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder edited answer with explanation